# ¿Como modifico un elemento de un FirestoreRecyclerAdapter?

Tags: android

Tengo un FirestoreRecyclerAdapter que me trae de la bd de firestore datos y los coloca de la manera que estableci en un layout, pero para este exclusivo quiero que sea del dia de hoy asi qeu hice este codigo,pero hasta ahora para los que no son del dia de hoy; no sé como hacer que desaparezcan ya que solo muestra el espacio porque los puse invisibles, porque como ven ahi solo he puesto invisible todo el linearLayout

```
 @Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull final Ventas ventas) {

    DocumentSnapshot ventasDocument = getSnapshots().getSnapshot(holder.getAdapterPosition());

    final String id = ventasDocument.getId();
    Date date = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat fecd = new SimpleDateFormat("d 'de' MMMM"); String numdiahoy = fecd.format(date);

    fecha = ventas.getFecha_Ven().toString();
    String dia = fecha.substring(fecha.indexOf(",") +2, fecha.indexOf("del")-1);

    if (numdiahoy.equals(dia)) {
        holder.tvNombrev.setText(ventas.getNom_Ven());
        holder.tvCelv.setText(String.valueOf(ventas.getCel_Ven()));
        holder.tvDirv.setText(ventas.getDir_Ven());
        holder.tvDatosv.setText(ventas.getDni_Ven());
        holder.tvPedidov.setText(ventas.getNom_Art());
        holder.tvtotalv.setText(String.valueOf(ventas.getTotal_Ven()));
        holder.tvCantv.setText(ventas.getNom_Uni());


    holder.btEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, updateVen.class);
            intent.putExtra("ventasId", id);
            activity.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    holder.btnDel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            AlertDialog.Builder dialogo = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity, R.style.ThemeDialogCustom);

            dialogo.setTitle("Eliminar");
            dialogo.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_cancel_24);
            dialogo.setCancelable(true);
            dialogo.setMessage("¿Deseas eliminar este pedido?");
            dialogo.setPositiveButton(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FFFFFFF'> Sí </font>"), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    miFirestore.collection("Ventas").document(id).delete().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            Toast.makeText(activity, "Eliminado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(activity, "No se eliminó", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            dialogo.setNegativeButton(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FFFFFFF'> No </font>"), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            dialogo.show();

        }
    });
    }else {
        holder.ej.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

no sé si lo que entendí es lo correcto.
¿Quieres mostrar en tu recyclerview los elementos de tu lista "ventas" en el día de hoy?

- Si eso es correcto, una opción sería.

1. Obtener la lista "Ventas"
2. Recorrer la lista con un bucle For y poner la condición para el día de hoy.
3. Los datos de la lista que pasen por la condición, añadirlos a una nueva variable List
4. Por último, esa variable es la que tienes que pasarle al Adaptador, de esa manera, solo cargas la lista con los elementos del día de hoy.

Un saludo